# Working in Local system but not when uploaded in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a simple form, onSubmit it takes the values to js page(AJAX CALL) then send to add.php page again returns the value to html page.
This code is working fine on my local system but when i test it in server AJAX call is not working.Even i just tested as on submit(click) alert from add.js(AJAX) but not working and works good in local(XAMP)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("sub");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
//alert('came');
var data=$("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
 
 $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),data,function(info){
  $("#result").html(info); 
});
});
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Ajax call
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uname">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <button id="sub">submit</button>
  </form>
  <span id="result"></span>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="add.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my add.php , which echo the result that will be displayed in my html result div tag   `

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['uname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
echo $name;
```

Is there anything to change while uploading in server.Whats wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Is there anything to change while uploading in server."_ - That's literally impossible for _us_ to answer. _"AJAX call is not working"_ - What happens? Have you checked the browsers console if you get any errors? Have you checked the network tab in your browsers dev tools to see if a request is made at all or what the request/response actually is? Please do some basic debugging and update your question to include the results.

Comment: no errors in console.I checked lot of times in both local and server.in local output is fine.But in server even not going to add.js(ajax page).console is clean in both test cases @MagnusEriksson

Comment: And the network tab?

Comment: I seen some syntax error in the above link

Comment: can u guide me ...where's going wrong.
Then how it's working in local? @SivaGanesh

Comment: I will post those things in my answer

Comment: plz,check the link once before answering @SivaGanesh

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
var btn=document.getElementById("sub");
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert('came');
        var data=$("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
        $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),data,function(info){
            $("#result").html(info);
            $('#myForm')[0].reset();*/ 
            //please have a look in your add.js:9:26
        });
    });
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
```

> Could you follow ajax in this method, Surely it will works for you.

```
        <button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="input-group-addon addbtn">Submit</button>




    function submit(){
        var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
         $.ajax({
                url: 'your url',
                type: "post",
                data: {'formSerialize':data, '_token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')},
                success: function(data){
                if(data.success==1){            
                      alert('success');    
                  }else if(data.error==1){
                     alert('error');     
                  }
                }
         });

}
```

**In your controller you can get the value like this**

```
parse_str($data['formSerialize'],$input);

In $input You can easily access all the field value.
```

Comment: i cleared these but output is not coming.Plz help me out.Expect output is name(eg: ramlal) and no. Which i echoed in add.php page

Comment: $("#myForm").submit(function() {
  return false;
}); can you explain this, Because on your submit it will return false

Comment: That is used for not refreshing the page `return false; `

Comment: @RamlalS making the button type="button" won't submit the form and you can get rid of this event binding

Comment: Then change it as input type

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the object you are sending to the server, you can see that it has not the structure that the server side 'add.php' is expecting, so there is no $_POST['uname'] variable. You may use a var_dump($_POST) to see the structure you are receiving or use $("#myForm").serialize() that I've used a lot and worked fin to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:** I'm not 100% sure what's causing your problem. But on my end I found the problem to be browser related since it worked on Chrome but not on FireFox.

One scenario would that FireFox didn't recognize your:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

It does happen that FireFox will do so if you don't abide by its standards. I did explain this in my answer about `event.preventDefault();`

I also completely changed your `add.js` as I've found some of your code unnecessary and that it could be combined into a cleaner function. Since you're already using jQuery might as well stick to it and not use DOM.

**FORM:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Ajax call
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="uname">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <span id="result"></span>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="add.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**ADD.JS**

```
//you need to add "event" as a parameter to the function since Firefox 
   //will not recognize event.preventDefault(); if its missing
$( "#myForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the form from submitting
    var form_data = $("#myForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: {form_data: form_data},
        success: function (info) {
            $("#result").html(info);
        }
    });
});
```

**ADD.PHP**

```
<?php
    $form_data = $_POST['form_data'];
    $params    = array();
    parse_str($form_data, $params);
    $name = $params['uname'];
    $age  = $params['age'];
    echo $name;
```

Comment: @NigelRen I'm in the middle of doing so. :)

Comment: OK - it shouldn't be a race to post an answer (unfortunately it can be at times).  I also sometimes find as I'm trying to explain my answers I find where I've made a mistake or wrong assumption (not saying you have,just trying to make a point).

Comment: @NigelRen It's alright. I do try to take my time answering sometimes and add new information along the way.

Comment: Waiting for your valuable answer @hungrykoala

Comment: @RamlalS did you try what I've posted? that's it

Comment: @RamlalS updated the code to include an update for `ADD.PHP` you can read more about `parse_str` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)